# Ошибка при работе с djangosaml2

Tags: python, django, active-directory

Для реализации SSO использую django и djangosaml2 работающие на windows с ADFS.

При обращении к адресу https://web.mydomain.com/saml2/metadata/ django выбрасывает исключение

```
Exception Value:    list index out of range

Exception Location:     C:\django_sites\venv\lib\site-packages\saml2\algsupport.py in get_algorithm_support, line 46
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пакет [djangosaml2](https://github.com/knaperek/djangosaml2) в своей работе использует исполняемые файлы xmlsec.

Сборку xmlsec для windows, а так же необходимые зависимости можно найти на [www.zlatkovic.com](http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html). На странице есть ссылка на [ftp](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/).

Необходимо скачать и распаковать все 8 архивов, а так же добавить в переменную среды окружения `PATH` пути к каталогам `bin`.

Проверить работоспособность можно с помощью консольной команды

`xmlsec1 --list-transforms` - одна из команд, которая вызывается при получении метаданных при обращении по URL `..../saml2/metadata

Если какая-то зависимость не установлена, то об этом уведомит сообщение об ошибке с названием отсутствующей dll.

Ошибка возникла из-за отсутствия необходимой dll в `PATH`.